# How I can get top YouTube search queries with YouTube API?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api

I have to get top search queries from YouTube. I'll appreciate any idea how to do this.

Comment: define 'top' - what does it mean to you?

Comment: e.g. top 100 most frequent quries